# C# - Export class/enum from another project to .dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, shared-libraries

I have here project `MDevice` (just a random name) that has an `enum`:

```
namespace MInterface {  

  [Serializable]
  public enum OMode : byte {
    Fly = 0x00,
    Die = 0x01,
    Cry = 0x02,
  }
}
```

Now I got another project `MInterfaceToSomethingElse` which is just a library-project which I want to use in another project.

Now here is the thing, I need the enum `OMode` in `MDevice` but I also need to make it public accessible in my .dll `MInterfaceToSomethingElse`.

Is there something like

```
namespace SomewhereInMInterfaceToSomethingElse {

   __exportToDll MInterface.OMode;

   // ...
}
```

I tried to keep it small and simple. The reason why I want to do this is because I am using a Java/C#.NET bridge for an Eclipse-Plugin. The framework that generates the bridge takes a look at all public classes and makes them accessible for me in a Java application (just so you guys know what I am doing this for).

Is there a way to do this? I want to avoid writing a wrapper class or create a 'shared' project that is included by both projects if possible..

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

put enum to class-library project which produce you a separate dll. Then reference to this dll (or project) in another projects (MDevice and MInterfaceToSomethingElse). Is this is what you need?

Comment: Would I need an additional project for this? Like `SharedStuff` which I'd have to add as additional dependency?